# Python Socket SSL OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (wh

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl, openssl

Full error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\my\python\code\server_ssl_testing.py", line 15, in <module>
    response = ssock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1228, in recv
    return super().recv(buflen, flags)
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

I created SSL Socket server and client, but then server try to receive info from client it falied and print error that is above this text.

Server:

```
import socket
import ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.load_cert_chain('certs/server-cert.pem', 'certs/server.key')

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as sock:
    sock.bind(('localhost', 2642))
    sock.listen(5)
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True) as ssock:
        conn, addr = ssock.accept()
        response = ssock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        print(response)
```

Client:

```
import socket
import ssl

hostname = 'localhost'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

sock = socket.create_connection((hostname, 2642))
ssock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname)
msg = "Hello World!"
ssock.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In server.py I should write `conn.recv` instead of `ssock.recv`.
Should help if anyone will want do it in future =)